# Boto3: Using boto3.resource('s3') to list all S3 buckets

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Is it possible to list all S3 buckets using a boto3 resource, ie `boto3.resource('s3')`?

I know that it's possible to do so using a low-level service client:

```
import boto3
boto3.client('s3').list_buckets()
```

However in an ideal world we can operate at the higher level of resources. Is there a method that allows us to to do and, if not, why?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [`s3.buckets.all()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/collections.html#boto3.resources.collection.CollectionManager):

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
  print(bucket.name)
```

Using list comprehension:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
buckets = [bucket.name for bucket in s3.buckets.all()]
print(buckets)
```

Answer (score 2):

Get `.buckets.pages()` from the `S3` resource and then loop through the pages to grab the buckets:

```
import boto3


buckets_iter = boto3.resource('s3').buckets.pages()
buckets = []
for bucket in buckets_iter:
    buckets += bucket

print(buckets)
```

I hope this helps.